# How to access API from AWS API Gateway with PHP SDK 3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

Can anyone help figure out how to use AWS Signature, AWS Credentials and PHP SDK 3 to access an API Gateway API? It seems like AWS Signature does not actually attach headers to a Guzzle request.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use Aws\Signature\SignatureV4;

$access_key = '<access_key>';
$secret_key = '<secret_key>';
$url = 'https://<api-id>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/camel?q=*';
$region = 'us-east-1';

$credentials = new Credentials($access_key, $secret_key);
var_dump($credentials);

$client = new Client();
$request = new Request('GET', $url);
var_dump($request);

$s4 = new SignatureV4("execute-api", $region);
$s4 = new SignatureV4("execute-api", "us-east-1");
$s4->signRequest($request, $credentials);
var_dump($s4);
var_dump($request);

$response = $client->send($request);
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 
'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message ' in 
/path/to/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on 
line 113

( ! ) GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET 
https://<api-id>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/camel?q=*` 
resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: {"message":"Missing 
Authentication Token"} in 
/path/to/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on 
line 113
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  234048  {main}( )   ../access.php:0
2   0.2801  486272  GuzzleHttp\Client->send( )  ../access.php:29
3   0.3787  574224  GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait( ) ../Client.php:106
```

Line 29 of access.php is:

```
$response = $client->send($request);
```

It doesn't appear from the var_dumps that any headers are being added. I am able to successfully test this endpoint in the API Gateway and in Postman. Enabling CORS does not appear to make a difference.

Has anyone solved this issue yet?

This issue is also covered at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/post!reply.jspa?messageID=795522 and https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=774631&tstart=0 but there are no solutions there.

Comment: Is `$s4->signRequest()` really supposed to be called in void context, or does it have a return value?

Comment: You are right, it does have a return value. I didn't read the documentation closely enough (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Signature.SignatureV4.html#_signRequest).

Comment: Nice work, solving that with little more than a suggestion of where you might want to start looking.  I didn't actually know the answer off hand, but any time I see what looks like a discarded return value, that's a red flag that *something* potentially useful is being thrown away, even if it's just a true/false pass/fail indication that requires interrogating something else to retrieve an error message... or, in this case, a new request with all the signing info added.

Comment: You are right; I should have been more careful. 

In my defense, it seems that the return value for signRequest() changed between AWS PHP SDK versions 2 and 3.

Comment: My comment was intended as a compliment, along with an explanation of the general thought process that led me to make the suggestion of what you might be overlooking.  If it came across as a criticism, I do apologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks, Michael, for your help above.

You have to use the return from new SignatureV4, which is a modified request.

```
$s4 = new SignatureV4("execute-api", $region);
$signedrequest = $s4->signRequest($request, $credentials);

$response = $client->send($signedrequest);

echo $response->getBody();
```

Answer (score -2):

Below code should work if you just want to query API GW services from php

```
<?php

 $curl = curl_init();

 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://<endpoint>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<service>",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<credentials>/20180705/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=<signature>",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
  ),
));

 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 $err = curl_error($curl);

 curl_close($curl);

 if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}

?>
```

Comment: Please use AWS Client API as it's standard